# why the labels is not display in chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

could you please tell me why the labels is  not display . ? I send the array of labels but it is not display   on label axis I send    this array

```
categories: [
                'Monday',
                'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday',
                'Thursday',
                'Friday',
                'Saturday',
                'Sunday',
                'ooo1',
                'ooow',
                'ooo23'
            ]
```

this label is not display why ?

```
                    'ooo1',
                    'ooow',
                    'ooo23'
```

**code**

http://jsfiddle.net/ogwsL7j3/5/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average fruit consumption during one week'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 250,
            y: 300,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Monday',
                'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday',
                'Thursday',
                'Friday',
                'Saturday',
                'Sunday',
                'ooo1',
                'ooow',
                'ooo23'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            enabled:false
        }
    },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' units'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            areaspline: {
                fillOpacity: 0.8
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not seeing ooo1, ooow and ooo23 is because there is no data for them, you need to assign them something, at least a 0:
Change this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12]
}]
```

To this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12,0,0,0]
}]
```

See you updated Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ogwsL7j3/7/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have that many data points as you have categories. Just increase the number of data points

```
...
data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8dotmpxj/